# Handling text and a new line character in Python's dominate module

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests, dominate

I am using dominate module in Python 3.7, I am not sure how to handle the new line characters that are existing in Python. As per my requirement the new line character `\n` should be converted to break character in HTML `<br>`. But that is not happening. The dominate module is ignoring the newline character which is not how I am expecting it to behave. Below is the code which I have tried.

```py
import dominate
from dominate.tags import *
text = "Hello\nworld!"
doc = dominate.document(title='Dominate your HTML')
with doc:
   h1(text)

with open("dominate22.html", 'w') as file:
   file.write(doc.render())
```

The output HTML code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dominate your HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, 
World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I have tried replacing the new line character with break character i.e `text.replace("\n", "<br>")`
But this was creating a string like `Hello<br>World`, which was not what I was expecting. Attaching the HTML code for the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dominate your HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello&lt;br&gt;world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The dominate module is ignoring the newline character which is not how I am expecting it to behave.

For the dominate library  the `\n` is just a character in a text string. It's not the same as a line break `<br>` HTML element so you have to do add it programmatically.

This example shows two approaches, using a context manager and adding nodes to an instance:

```py
import dominate

from dominate.tags import h1, h2, br
from dominate.util import text

the_string = "Hello\nworld!"
doc = dominate.document(title='Dominate your HTML')

with doc:
    parts = the_string.split('\n')

    with h1():  # using a context manager
        text(parts[0])
        br()
        text(parts[1])

    header = h2()  # same as above but adding nodes
    header.add(text(parts[0]))
    header.add(br())
    header.add(text(parts[1]))


with open("dominate22.html", 'w') as file:
    file.write(doc.render())
```

Gives this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dominate your HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello<br>world!</h1>
    <h2>Hello<br>world!</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```